# How to disable deprecated messages in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I use Joomla v1.5, and after installing same components I got deprecated messages - how can I disable this messages in Joomla? I can't disable it in php.ini, because I don't have access for php in server.

Comment: How about instead of ignoring warnings about your code being extremely outdated , you would fix them instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put in the index.php file, after this line `define( '_JEXEC', 1 );`, this statement:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

or, as [pderaaij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673696/pderaaij) says, use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

As he says,

> In this way all of the other errors are shown, except the deprecated
>   messages.

Comment: A bit nicer: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED); this way all of the other errors are shown, except the deprecated messages.

Comment: placing error_reporting in multiple locations inside the code is bad practice as it should ideally only be set once. The Joomla 1.5 core code sets the error_reporting as appropriately configured in the global configuration.

Comment: ghbarratt In my case, setting it in the global configuration didn't work. Doing Aurelio De Rosa's answer did, without giving my site 500 page error. And your solution in the htaccess file gave my site 500 errors, so let's agree that there are many ways to skin a fish.

Answer (score 5):

The ideal solution is to set the global configuration setting called "Error Reporting" to either "None" or to "System Default" and then set the "system default" through the use of an .htaccess file on the web root or in the httpd/apache conf.

To set the value in the .htaccess file you can use:

```
php_value error_reporting 22527
```

(you can verify this value using php: `echo E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED;`)

AurelioDeRosa's answer proposes to "hack" (!) the core of Joomla. As stated in my comment, placing error_reporting in multiple locations inside the code is bad practice as it should ideally only be set once. The Joomla 1.5 core code sets the error_reporting as appropriately configured in the global configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I have added this at the begining of index.php and it fixed it:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Thanks Aurelio De Rosa

Answer (score 1):

I added the following in  .htaccess file in joomla:

> php_value allow_call_time_pass_reference 1

and it worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try add to index.php

`ini_set('allow_call_time_pass_reference', 1);`

or to .htaccess

> `php_value allow_call_time_pass_reference  1`

But it depends what is causing the problem and also server configuration if you are allowed to change php configuration.

Comment: This is not a good tip as you can read here: "In PHP 5, allow_call_time_pass_reference is deprecated, in versions prior to PHP 5.3.0, use of this feature will emit an E_COMPILE_WARNING, and in PHP 5.3.0+, the warning is a E_DEPRECATED notice."