# Need help moving my joomla website to another server

Tags: php, joomla

Good day, i tried moving my joomla 1.5 website to another server and i made sure that i downloaded all the content and made necessary changes to my configuration.php file i.e changing the database name and username to my current server details to be precisely, i added the site as an addon domain i.e to say that it's not my default website, then when i try to view my site i get the following error codes on the attached image, please i need solution thanks.!

> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 29
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/loader.php on line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 32
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/loader.php on line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/loader.php on line 161
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/loader.php on line 138
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 33
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 463
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 464
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 465
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 466
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 467
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php on line 468
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 35
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/loader.php on line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in /home/midwater/public_html/worldsms/libraries/joomla/import.php on line 38

Comment: Please don't screenshot error messages. Copy and paste the text here so we can actually read it.

Comment: Please don't close as off topic without providing the link to the correct question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746303/how-to-disable-deprecated-messages-in-joomla  (And how can it be off-topic if it was previously asked and answered?)  I wish I could downvote "closed as off topic" actions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your new server is displaying all warnings. That could be due to a newer php version or just the ini setting.

You can turn it off, but fixing the problems would be a better idea. If they're yours to fix of course...

To avoid displaying the warnings, you can use:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

somewhere at the top (don't know where that is with Joomla exactly).

You could also change it in your php.ini file. Look for something like:

```
display_errors 1    // or On
```

and change it to:

```
display_errors 0    // or Off
```

The problems could also be solved in a newer version of Joomla so you should check if you have the latest version.

Comment: +1 good answer. I would also suggest mentioning that Joomla 1.5 may run into some issues with PHP 5.4+ as it was not developed for such a high PHP version ;)

Comment: @Lodder Thanks. Do you have a reference for that? I am not that familiar with Joomla...

Comment: [Technical Requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html). Recommended PHP version for J1.5 is 5.2 and minimum is 4.3.10, so as you can imagine, it's an old version of Joomla. I do not know of any specific issues with PHP 5.4+, however it is very likely as some functions have been deprecated/removed since 5.2

Comment: @Lodder Thanks, I will check it out when I am back at my computer.

Comment: @lodder, but the previous server was php version 5.4 and the website was running smooth then

Comment: In which case you simply need to disable strict error reporting, preferably in your *php.ini*. I would strongly suggest thinking about migrating to Joomla 3.x as 1.5 is extremely old and unsupported